# Separar valor de entrada e valor esperado no pytest.mark.parametrize

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como separo o parametrize, a entrada do esperado

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('entrada, esperado',
                         [(1,0,0,), (1,0,)
                        ])

def testa_raizes(entrada, esperado):
    assert b.calcula_raizes(entrada) == (esperado)
```

Comment: Em qual função está aplicando esse decorador? Você definiu os argumentos como `entrada` e `esperado`?

Comment: Sim, acabei de editar a pergunta, postando o método que recebe a entrada e o valor esperado para ser testado.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você usa o paramtrize, o segundo parâmetro é uma sequência (que pode ser uma lista), ond cada elemento e uma outra sequência que contém um item para cada parâmetro da função.

Você quer que a sequência (1, 0, 0)  seja atribuida a variável "entrada", no entanto do jeito que você fez, o pytest vai pegar o "1" e atribuir a "entrada" e o "0" atribuir a "esperado" (e provavelmente dar um erro por que sobrou um terceiro 0).

Você quer usaressas duas sequências de uma vez, em um único teste - então
tem que criar uma sequência com elas:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('entrada, esperado', [
    [(1,0,0,), (1,0,)],
])
def testa_raizes(entrada, esperado):
    assert b.calcula_raizes(entrada) == (esperado)
```

Agora sim, o pytest pega o primeiro elemento da lista de entradas que você passa no parametrize - esse elemento é `[(1,0,0,), (1,0,)],`. Ele pega oprimeiro elmento daí - `(1,0,0)` e passa como "entrada", e `(1,0)` como "esperado".

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim, considerando que talvez você tenha passado parâmetros a,b,c :

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('entrada1, entrada2, entrada3, esperado', [(1,0,0,(1,0))])

def testa_raizes(entrada1, entrada2, entrada3, esperado):
    assert b.calcula_raizes(entrada1, entrada2, entrada3) == esperado
```